# What's objectionable about the utf8_roman_520_ci collation?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

I was reading MySQL worklog [WL#2673: Unicode Collation Algorithm new version](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2673), which was about implementing Unicode Collation Algorithm 5.2 in MySQL. Excerpt from the document:

```
Language collations
===================
WL#2673 will add only _unicode_520_ci collations.

Language collations will be implemented in separate
worklog tasks.

utf8_general_ci                         never
utf8_bin                                never
utf8_unicode_520_ci                     now
[...]
utf8_roman_520_ci                       later (grumble grumble ...)
[...]
```

What's wrong with the `utf8_roman_520_ci` collation? It is because it is useless? If so, why was it implemented?

Comment: The roman collation is associated with Classical Latin, which is a dead language, only interesting to scholars. So I would guess that the person who wrote "grumble grumble" doesn't feel that it is worth the time to update a collation that probably few if any users of MySQL will ever employ.

Comment: It's a curious one -- `U` and `V` are treated as equal.  However, u with an accent comes before `U`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html